# Should this be a separate answer?

Tags: discussion

In [this Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457277/230769) the Question originally contained an incorrect command (`passwd password` instead of `passwd username`). My [first Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457278/230769) correctly answers the title ("How to change password in brand new Unix user") and addresses the question as it originally stood.

Through edits and comments, the real issue arose - the password didn't meet the requirements. Should a second Answer be posted with an explanation of the message `The password contains less than 1 digits`? Should the existing Answer be appended? I think since the original Answer is a useful answer to "How to change password", so I think the original Answer's content should be preserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create 2 sections to your answer and explain why you have 2 sections. Put the correct answer at the top and put the original answer below it in it's own section.

---

Something like this:

#### Updated Answer

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim ei malis possim quodsi. Ferri contentiones comprehensam ex qui, pro paulo decore ne. Nominati consequuntur mei eu. At possit scribentur vix. Appellantur concludaturque ex pri. No dico meis labitur per. Eu mei legere probatus, ut fuisset adolescens qui.

#### Original Answer

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vim ei malis possim quodsi. Ferri contentiones comprehensam ex qui, pro paulo decore ne. Nominati consequuntur mei eu. At possit scribentur vix. Appellantur concludaturque ex pri. No dico meis labitur per. Eu mei legere probatus, ut fuisset adolescens qui.